# How to display/hide multiple ion-input on the value of number from ion-select?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have one ion-select which is having 1 to 10 value in ion-option.

```
<ion-label> Select how many input fields</ion-label>
<ion-select> 
<ion-option value="0"> Zero</ion-option>
<ion-option value="1"> One</ion-option>
.
.
.
<ion-option value="10"> Ten</ion-option>
 </ion-select>
```

After that i have have 10 input box to display.

```
<ion-input formControlName="1_box"></ion-input>
..
.
.
.<ion-input formControlName="10_box"></ion-input>
```

I need to hide all input box if ion-option == 0, And display the input box on the basis of quantity selected in n ion-select.

It means display only 4 input box if ion-select 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you create an array of input like `boxes = [];` and put up a

```
<ion-select (cancel)="onCancel()" (change)="onChange()">
  <ion-option value="1">One</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="2">Two</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="3">Three</ion-option> 
</ion-select>
```

onto `ion-select`. Everytime you change, check the value and increase or decrease the number of inputs from the `boxes[]` array.

For Display you can loop them in a `table` or `div` or `ng-container`. So everytime, you'll input a value for the box.

`<div *ngFor="let box in boxes">
<input [(ngModel)]="box" />
</div>`